# Modifying [current-page:page-number] token

Tags: tokens, paging

I am using [current-page:page-number] token in title and metatag description. Pager in views, gives second page of view as "Page 1" and token gives first page of view as "Page 1".

This creates difference in URL`s and title tag, such as :
Title: Daily News - Page 2 | example.com
URL: http://example.com/news?page=1

How to decrease value of [current-page:page-number] token by 1?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to achieve this by modifying token.tokens.inc. At line 755, I added this code :

```
 if ((int)$page>0)
      { $page_num = $page;
      $replacements[$original] = " - Page ".$page_num;
      }
      else  
      $replacements[$original] = "";
      break;
```

Is there any cleaner way to do it by writing custom module or hook?

Comment: You should read this article 
https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/how-and-why-patch-drupal-module
before hack any contrib module.

Comment: Thank you Abdulla. The article is quite helpful and I will try to create patch for my hack.